# connecting all points (possible conbination) in scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, line

Here is small dataset:

```
myd <- data.frame(PC1 = rnorm(5, 5, 2), 
PC2 = rnorm (5, 5, 3), label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
plot(myd$PC1, myd$PC2)
text( myd$PC1-0.1, myd$PC2, lab = myd$label)
```

I want connect all possible combination between line with straight (euclidean) distance, to produce some graph like this (preferrably in base graphics or ggplot2)

[image: 2D graph with five points, with a line drawn from each point to each other point]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the base plot solution:

```
plot(myd$PC1, myd$PC2)
apply(combn(seq_len(nrow(myd)), 2), 2, 
      function(x) lines(myd[x, ]$PC1, myd[x, ]$PC2))
```

[image]

Here is the ggplot2 solution:

```
ps <- data.frame(t(apply(combn(seq_len(nrow(myd)), 2), 2, 
                         function(x) c(myd[x, ]$PC1, myd[x, ]$PC2))))
qplot(myd$PC1, myd$PC2) +
  geom_segment(data = ps, mapping = aes(x = X1, xend = X2, y = X3,yend = X4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In ggplot you can use `geom_segment` to draw the connecting lines.

But first you have to construct a data frame with the co-ordinates of each connecting line. Use `combn()` to find all combinations:

```
comb <- combn(nrow(myd), 2)
connections <- data.frame(
  from = myd[comb[1, ], 1:2],
  to   = myd[comb[2, ], 1:3]
)
names(connections) <- c("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2", "label")
```

Then plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(myd, aes(PC1, PC2)) + 
  geom_point(col="red", size=5) + 
  geom_segment(data=connections, aes(x=x1, y=y1, xend=x2, yend=y2), col="blue")
```

[image]